# Creating dynamic sublists from a list /sequence in python

Tags: python

Im trying to write a function that creates  set of dynamic sublists each containing 5 elements from a list passed to it.Here's my attempt at the code

```
def sublists(seq):
    i=0
    x=[]
    while i<len(seq)-1:
        j=0
        while j<5:
            X.append(seq[i]) # How do I change X after it reaches size 5?
     #return set of sublists
```

EDIT:

Sample input: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Expected output: `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]`

Comment: It's not clear what output do you expect. Give us example please.

Comment: Then it is the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, you'll need to (or at least should) have two lists, a temporary one and a permanent one that you return (Also you will need to increase j and i or, more practically, use a for loop, but I assume you just forgot to post that).

*EDIT* removed first code as the style given doesn't match easily with the expected results, see other two possibilities.

Or, more sensibly:

```
def sublists(seq):
    x=[]
    for i in range(0,len(seq),5):
        x.append(seq[i:i+5])
    return x
```

Or, more sensibly again, a simple list comprehension:

```
def sublists(seq):
    return [seq[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(seq),5)]
```

When given the list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

They will return

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: :Great answer! I really wanted your second explanation , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By "dynamic sublists", do you mean break up the list into groups of five elements? This is similar to your approach:

```
def sublists(lst, n):
    ret = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        ret.append(seq[i:i+n])
        i += n
    return ret
```

Or, using iterators:

```
def sublists(seq, n):
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        r = list(itertools.islice(it, 5))
        if not r:
            break
        yield r
```

which will return an iterator of lists over list of length up to five. (If you took out the `list` call, weird things would happen if you didn't access the iterators in the same order.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`itertools.combinations(...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

For example:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(combinations(l, 5))
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: doesnt help to solve my issue, please look at the edited question!

Comment: @KodeSeeker my apologies, I misunderstood the intent of your question.